# Error to install libraries with spark in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was trying to install oauth library with spark in codeigniter with the next command:

```
php tools/spark install -v0.4.0 oauth2
```

But I recived a error message like this:

```
[ SPARK ] Retrieving spark detail from getsparks.org
[ ERROR ] Uh-oh!
[ ERROR ] Unable to find spark: oauth2 (0.4.0) in any sources
```

This to pass with all libraries that I can to install. Sparks are in myapp_ci/tools:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr2xR.png)

Comment: check this https://github.com/mistymagich/codeigniter-oauth2-sample/tree/master/tools

Comment: Thanks Abdulla, I tryed this but I have the same error :(

Comment: Oh no, Sparks is dead :( Sorry, I am new in this theme.

Comment: @JuanMorales if you've found that spark is dead, you can post that as an answer to your own question so others can find it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is dead. If you want to handle dependencies, You can to use Composer instead.